# Finding $\gamma \in S_7$ that satisfies $\gamma^4=(3412675)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I have proved it using an arbitrary $\tau=(1234567)$, taking it to the fourth power, and finding that $\tau^4=(1526374)$.

Can I just see the pattern of where each element went and match it to the $\gamma^4$?

Comment: You can find a mathjax tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) PS: Suits is awesome

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. This is my first question asked. Now I will not look like a fool for next time. PS: Suits IS awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Since $\gamma^4$ is a $7$-cycle, so is $\gamma$. Then, what is $(\gamma^4)^2$?

Comment: Ok, I think I have it. Since 8=1(mod 7), and the order of gamma is 7, the eighth power of gamma would also be gamma.

Comment: Bingo. :) $\!\!$

Answer (score 0):

Travi's solutions is pretty neat. Alternatively observe a cycle can only break into smaller cycles when exponentiationg, so $\gamma$ is a $7$ cycle.

What then build the $7$ cycle:

$(1***5**)\rightarrow (12**5**)\rightarrow (12**56*)\rightarrow (123*56*)\rightarrow (123*567)\rightarrow (1234567)$